# Image height returns 0 using .load

Tags: jquery, height

```
$(".sl3-big-image").on('load', function() {
      alturaImg3 = $('.sl3-big-image').height();
      $('.sl3-container').css('height',alturaImg3);
      $('.sl3-container .sl2-container2').css('height',alturaImg3);
    });
```

I think `.on('load',...)` is not working at all.. Sometimes img height is 0. I tried this but it's not working either.

```
$(".sl3-big-image").on('load', function() {
          alturaImg3 = $('.sl3-big-image').height();
          $('.sl3-container').css('height',alturaImg3);
          $('.sl3-container .sl2-container2').css('height',alturaImg3);
        }).each(function() {
          if(this.complete) $(this).load();
        });
```

What could be the problem? Thanks

Comment: I think you need `$(this).height()`

Comment: Number of things could be wrong. Hard to say without seeing your HTML, and even CSS (you could have `img { height: 0 }` etc). Try `naturalHeight` if you're using Chrome to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your function inside window.load function.

```
$(window).load(function(e){
  $(".sl3-big-image").on('load', function() {
          alturaImg3 = $(this).height();
          $('.sl3-container').css('height',alturaImg3);
          $('.sl3-container .sl2-container2').css('height',alturaImg3);
        }).each(function() {
          if(this.complete) $(this).load();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `height` attribute of `this` works just fine.

```js
$image = $('img');

$image.on('load', function () {
  console.log(this.height);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-GEUSBr1DEWw/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAALg/28aKu1XOjeE/photo.jpg" alt="" />
```